# How can I run a python script to generate/update a JSON file in an S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, amazon-s3

**MY QUESTION: How can I run a python script to generate/update a JSON file in an S3 bucket? Also, should I run this script every time a file gets added to my bucket, or when someone visits my webpage?**

**Read on for description...**

I have a website hosted on AWS, my static pages are in a public S3 bucket. The purpose is to share music I've written with music students. I have a Python script which scans all the objects (sheet music PDFs) in a folder in the same S3 bucket. The Python script then creates a JSON file that has the names of all the s3 objects along with [generated URLs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html) for each object.

Heres how that JSON file is formatted:

```
{
  "bass": [{
      "bass-song1": "http://www.website.com/bass-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "bass-song2": "http://www.website.com/bass-song2.pdf"
    }],
  "drum": [{
      "drum-song1": "http://www.website.com/drum-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "drum-song2": "http://www.website.com/drum-song2.pdf"
    }],
  "guitar": [{
      "guitar-song1": "http://www.website.com/guitar-song1.pdf"
    }, {
      "guitar-song2": "http://www.website.com/guitar-song2.pdf"
    }]
}
```

My working Python script, for reference:

```
import boto3
import json
import pprint

# This program creates a json file
# with temporary URLs for bucket objects, organized by folder
# For use with javascript that generates links to bucket objects for website

# create a session to retrieve credentials from ~/.aws/credentials
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='<MY PROFILE>')

# use your credentials to create a low-level client with the s3 service
s3 = session.client('s3')

# Store dictionary of objects from bucket that starts with the prefix '__'
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='<MY BUCKET>', Prefix='<FOLDER IN BUCKET>')

folder_list = []
url_json = {}

# (the value of 'Contents' is a list of dictionaries)
# For all the dictionaries in the 'Contents' list,
# IF they don't end with '/' (meaning, if its not a directory)...
for i in response['Contents']:
    if i['Key'].endswith('/') != True:

        # get the directory of the current Key, save as string in 'dir'
        full_path = i['Key']
        # this retrieves the folder after '__'
        dir = full_path.split("/")[1]
        # capitalize the directory name, update variable
        dir = dir.capitalize()
        # this retrieves the file name
        filename = full_path.split("/")[2]

        # if the name of the directory ('dir') is not in folder_list:
        # add it to folder_list,
        # and add an item to dictionary 'url_json' where key is current 'dir' and value is empty list
        if dir not in folder_list:
            folder_list.append(dir)
            url_json[folder_list[-1]] = []

        # generate a temporary URL for the current bucket object
        url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket':'<MY BUCKET>', 'Key':i['Key']}, ExpiresIn=3600)

        # create a dictionary for each bucket object
        # store the object's name (Key) and URL (value)
        object_dict = {filename:url}

        # Append the newly created URL to a list in the 'url_json' dictionary,
        # whose key is the last directory in 'folder_list'
        url_json[folder_list[-1]].append(object_dict)

# Dump content of 'url_json' directory to 'urls.json' file
# if it already exists, overwrite it
with open('url_list.json', mode='w') as outfile:
    json.dump(url_json, outfile)
```

Also, in the body of my webpage I wrote some in-line JavaScript that loads/reads the JSON file, and uses the URLs and their associated text to create links for people to access those files on my webpage.

My working JavaScript, for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

async function getData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json()
}

async function main() {
  const data = await getData('<JSON FILE URL>');

  // 'instrument' example: 'Bass'
  for (var instrument in data) {

    var h = document.createElement("H3"); // Create the H1 element
    var t = document.createTextNode(instrument); // Create a text element
    h.appendChild(t); // Append the text node to the H1 element
    document.body.appendChild(h); // Append the H1 element to the document body

    // store the list of bass songs
    var song_list = data[instrument]
    // for each song (list element),
    for (var song_object of song_list) {
      // for every song name in the object (in python, dictionary)
      for (var song_name in song_object) {
        // create a var with the name and URL of the PDF song file
        var link_str = song_name;
        var link_url = song_object[song_name];

        // Create link to appear on website
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
        a.href = link_url;
        a.innerText = link_str;
        a.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        document.body.append(lineBreak);
      }
    }
  }
}
main();

</script>
```

**So my end goal is this:**
I upload a PDF file to my S3 bucket, my Python script executes to update the JSON file in my S3 bucket, and when someone visits my webpage the JavaScript will parse the JSON file to create links to those PDF files. Should I have the python script create the JSON when I upload files into the bucket, or when someone visits the website? The issue is that these object URLs have a [time expiration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html)... but I also don't want to be running code every time someone loads a page (for $$ reasons).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need anymore info from me.
Thank you,
Sebastian.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use pre-signed URLs? Do you not want them to be always public? Will users authenticate to obtain the JSON file? Ensuring privacy will result in a different design to being publicly accessible, so it's worth deciding up-front.

Comment: If the pre-signed URLs can be avoided, then you could use Amazon S3 Events to trigger a Python AWS Lambda function whenever you add a new file. The code could then list the objects and create a JSON file. Thus, it only ever runs when the files change.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll avoid pre-signed URLs in lieu of the S3 event trigger option, but how do I programmatically get the new object's public URL? I wasn't able to find the call for that

Comment: The URL is: `BUCKET-NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/OBJECT-KEY`  If you have a Domain Name associated with a bucket, then you could use `www.website.com/OBJECT-KEY`